# Is it against to MVC pattern calling a view in another view with variables?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, seo

**edited for clarification and modified example pseudo-code**

I was trying to understand the concept of mvc and sometimes it gives me some serious headaches.

I was facing with a problem and trying to think a solution. I am using codeigniter and the problem is how to make different page titles and descriptions for different categories and searches in my web site.

Here is the solution I thought (I know it's not the best way the demonstrate it but don't stuck in details just look at the basic idea):

controller

```
 $data['results'] = call model and get results
 this->load->view(ad_details,$results);
```

ad_categories view:

```
foreach ($results as $key => $row) {
        $ad_title = $row->title; 
        $ad_id = $row->id;
        $ad_price = $row->price;
        $ad_status = $row->status;
        $ad_city = $row->city;
        $ad_user = $row->user;
        if ($key<1) {
          // let's be sure even customers enter same info we got unique titles and descriptions for search engines 
         $data['title'] = "$ad_title $ad_id $ad_price";
         $data['description'] = "Second Hand Autos for $ad_status from $ad_user in $ad_city";
         this->load->view(header,$data);
         <body>
        }
      $ad_description = $row->description; 
      <h2>$ad_title</h2>
      <p>$ad_description</p>
      }
      </body>
     <? this->load->view(footer); ?>
```

header_view file

```
<!doctype html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title><?=$title?></title>
        <META NAME="description" CONTENT="<?=$description">
        <META NAME="keywords" CONTENT="<?=$keywords?>" >    
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="js/libs/modernizr-2.0.6.min.js"></script>              
    </head>
     <body>
```

The actual titles and descriptions can be quite different, there can be some exceptions and I may have to use different codes for different categories and different search pages. So, doing it in that way against MVC or is there better way to do that?

In that way, I’m trying to avoid using same foreach loops multiple times in controller or in views. 
the actual titles and descriptions can be quite different, there can be some exceptions and i may have to use different codes for different categories and different search pages. So, is doing it in that way against mvc or is there better way to do that ?

Comment: There is no harm in using multiple views in one controller method. A views is actually a visual template for rendering a page and your page can be made of any number of components say header, footer, sidebars etc. The only rule I follow in a view is I do not transform data or do any business logic handling, this should be done at controller.

Comment: using multiple views is not the point. the point is i am trying to avoid using multiple and same foreach loops in every different controller. for example, if i don't connect views in that way, that means i have to use a foreach loop of $result in headers.php to preparing $title, $description, $keywords variables and a second foreach loop for $results. isn't that against don't repeat yourself motto ?

Comment: Oh! In that case use libraries in CI. Move all your similar looking code to libraries and load them as and when required and call the method. For example you may have a library method which actually over rides the default meta data for a page say search result page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** I've learned from reading the comments to this that you can't use `$results[0]` in CodeIgniter, you have to use `$results->row()` apparently - I'm leaving my answer as it was because it wasn't supposed to be 100% CI-specific, but bear it in mind.

---

Here's the way I'd have written your view:

```
<?php $this->load->view('header', array(
  'title' => $results[0]->title.' '.$results[0]->id.' '.$results[0]->price,
  'description' => 'Second hand autos for '.$results[0]->status.' from '.$results[0]->user.' in '.$results[0]->city
)); ?>
<body>
  <h2><?php echo htmlspecialchars($results[0]->title); ?></h2>
  <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($results[0]->description); ?></p>

  <?php foreach($results as $row): ?>
    <!-- Deal with results -->
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  </body>
 <? this->load->view('footer'); ?>
```

Here you can see I've eliminated the foreach loop except where you're actually dealing with each of the results in turn. Having said that, my personal opinion is that you're taking the "don't repeat yourself" mantra a little bit too far, to the extent that you're sacrificing code readability/maintainability for its sake. If combining multiple foreach loops into one makes the code more difficult to understand, don't do it.

I've also tried to cut down on the amount of PHP and variable assignments in the view, which is usually a good thing, but this too can be inconvenient if pushed too far. For instance, you might want to cut down on all the `$results[0]->` stuff by doing this right at the top of your view:

```
$r = $results[0];
```

Then again, you might not. Whatever quacks your duck. :)

Comment: I think i have to use arrays instead of objects for this because i'm getting this error with your solution :  Fatal error</b>:  Cannot use object of type CI_DB_mysql_result as array in

Comment: i think i have found the solution: well not exactly of yours but pretty similar to it, therefore you may wanna say your opinion on this:

<?php 
$r = $results->row(); 

  $this->load->view('header', array(
  'title' => $r->title.' '.$r->id.' '.$r->price,
  'description' => 'Second hand autos for '.$r->status.' from '.$r->user.' in '.$r->city
)); ?>

According to codeigniter's useful manual "-row() or row_array()" can be used for fetching only a row in a sql result set.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Comment: You can blame my unfamiliarity with CodeIgniter for that. Thanks, I'll make a little edit to make it clear for anyone who reads my answer. :)

Answer (score 6):

Since MVC is a design pattern and not a syntax rule, you've a certain degree of freedom here. I see nothing wrong in using a view inside a view, and not only it's possibile in CI, but it's so thought out that you can call different views and nest them withouth having to pass the "secondary" view its set of data, as views are buffered and they will available to all anyways.

SO you can do something like:

controller:

```
$data['results'] = $this->your_model->get_details();
// this will be in the form of an array returned directly from the model 
// i.e. the model code would look someting like:
// $data = array();
// foreach($query->result() as $row)
// {
//   $data[] = $row;
// }
// return $data;

$this->load->view('ad_details',$data);
```

In ad_details.php:

```
<?php $this->load->view('header');?>
<!-- html code -->
<? $this->load->view('footer'); ?>
```

If you var_dump() it, you will see that both the header.php and footer.php will have a variable $results now, without having to pass it again.

Comment: but i can't access "$title $description $keywords" variables from header view. do i have to use foreach loops multiple times in every view ?

Comment: Assign the inside the controller, or if your array is just a single row (thinking about it now, seeing your code better) just user $result->title

Comment: May be i should be more clear on my question. I'm trying to avoid using same foreach loops multiple times. That's the reason behind that question and i'm not sure why using same foreach loops multiple times is better and logical way to do that.

Answer (score 3):

MVC is there to keep your life easier and your development faster, if you cannot call it from the controller level and it's permitted to call it inside the view, do so.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you want to have one model - one view with the relationship and data/flow controlled via some controller. A controller can manage multiple models and views but each distinct view should have a corresponding model.

It would be a good idea to read up on ASP NET MVC.

Comment: isn't that against don't repeat yourself motto ? do i have to write header and footer parts in every time ?

Comment: If every single page is using the same model, then yes, but if every single page is using a different model then you shouldn't be using the same views. I think you should move logic (`$data['title']`) to the controller though.

Answer (score 2):

Handle your logic in the controller.

in general, this means loop and conditionals which **decide what** to display stay out of the view.  the view can use logic to **decide how** to display stuff, looping to create tables, etc.

put all this in the controller.

```
$data['results'] = call model and get results
$this->load->view(ad_details,$results);
foreach ($results as $key => $row) {
    if ($key<1) {
      // let's be sure even customers enter same info we got unique titles and descriptions      for search engines 
     $data['title'] = "$ad_title $ad_id $ad_price";
     $data['description'] = "Second Hand Autos for $ad_status from $ad_user in $ad_city";
     this->load->view(header,$data);
    }
this->load->view(body, data);
```

Comment: is that means i should use a second foreach loop of $result in body view ? isn't that against don't repeat yourself motto ? i was looking for a way, which allows me to not repeating same foreach loops again and again.

Comment: do you currently have a single foreach that handles body and ads ?  i'm just moving them into another layer.  your code will be as complex as the problem...

Comment: i have edited example for clarification. probably it was vague in first version. there is a probability it can be just one row but mostly, it can be 15 ads per page. like this:

http://tinyurl.com/motto-examplepage